# Error connecting to MariaDB Platform: Unknown database 'main'

Tags: python-3.x, docker, phpmyadmin, mariadb

**Context :**

My python+docker project runs fine on my windows environment. When I try to run it on my debian 10 vps with the same containers and python codes i get this error :

`Error connecting to MariaDB Platform: Unknown database 'main'`

**Code :**
This is the python code to connect to the "main" database.

```
    try:
        self.conn = mariadb.connect(
            user=config['DATABASE']['user'],
            password=config['DATABASE']['password'],
            host=config['DATABASE']['host'],
            port=int(config['DATABASE']['port']),
            database=config['DATABASE']['database']
        )
    except mariadb.Error as e:
        print(f"Error connecting to MariaDB Platform: {e}")
        sys.exit(1)
```

**Notes :**

- I have the 1.1.6 mariadb python library.
- I've used an PHPMyadmin container to make sure there was a "main" database.
- Deleting/adding a new "main" database.
- Reinstalling mariadb python library.
- Recreate mariadb container.

Comment: docker is supposed to make projects easy. Why do I see so many docker questions ?